# How to change large amounts of data into string array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-analysis

The data i have is about 2000 items
I use visual studio code predominantly

How can i format this data to a string array without putting quotes around each  item manually using JavaScript.

```
var array = [
  a2kjda   
  a2dkj1  
  1js1j2  
  sldkjs                  
  dkljf1
]
```

Comment: Don't forget the commas.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What does the data look like? What does this have to do with Visual Studio Code? Do you want a string array as expressed in JavaScript, e.g. text like `[ 1, 2, 3, 4]` or you want a function that takes your data and returns an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you select all of the array items with your cursor and press `Shift, Option and I` then it will add a cursor to the end of every line. Enter your `"` for the end of the item and then use `Option and Left Arrow` to skip to the beginning to add your opening `"`.

The keyboard commands may be slightly different if you're on Windows. Search the Visual Studio Code key bindings for 'Add cursors to line ends' if you want to know the shortcut for your OS.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it worked @user388297. If you have solved your problem you should mark the answer as correct so other users know you no longer have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single string with a delimiter and then split on it like this:

```
var data = "a2kjda|a2dkj1|1js1j2|sldkjs|dkljf1".split("|");

console.log(data[2]); // will print 1js1j2
```